# Watching Other Applications With Ruby

Tags: ruby, memory-management, monitoring

I was wondering if it was even possible with RUBY to watch other applications and if a certain application is below a memory threshold it kills it and starts it again.

Operating System would be Windows 7+

Things I need to be able to do:

1. Monitor Memory
2. Determine between different processes
3. Kill Processes
4. Start new process (bat script or powershell)
5. Start monitoring again

The watched application running would run high memory when it is working and that is good.  If it goes below 1gb I want this application to kill it. Of course when it restarts it would give a grace period for it to load the RAM.

I was going to use the Shoes gui framework to make something nice to wrap around it.  It would be theoretically nice to have some sort of auto detection if the application is running.

If this is possible, but requires Gem you think may help I would like to hear about them.

I found Usagewatch Gem seems to be headed the right way, but from a glance at the documentation it is general and I need to be specific about which process I am watching.

If this question is not appropriate here please let me know via a comment and I will remove it and/or move it to a proper place for this type of question to be asked.

I appreciate your time and effort into helping me with this endeavor.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [win32 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/win32-api). Than start by looking through the [Win32 Api documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx). This will give you the most flexible solution and will give you the whole system programming power for Windows. My advice is to make some wrapper functions about the things connected with Windows you need and use them that way,  so if you find a more appriete solution you can switch to it easily.

Comment: So I would have to encapsulate the other application with this program in order to monitor and kill it?

Comment: No need the win32 api gives you the ability to find the PID of your app. Search something about [Process manipulation](http://www.uni-hildesheim.de/rz/DOC/perl/html/site/lib/Win32/Process.html)